# How to write a SQL query to get the count of the distinct object

Tags: sql

There is a table "OBJECTS" with one column "OBJECT_NAME" having three values OBJ1, OBJ2, OBJ3.
Snapshot of the table OBJECTS is:

```
OBJECT_NAME
----------
OBJ3
OBJ1
OBJ2
OBJ1
OBJ1
OBJ2
```

how to write a efficient SQL query to get output the count of the distinct object in the format as shown below.

```
OBJ1_Count OBJ2_COUNT OBJ3_COUNT
--------------------------------- 
3              2           1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select
  sum(case when [object_name] = 'OBJ1' then 1 else 0 end) as obj1_count,
  sum(case when [object_name] = 'OBJ2' then 1 else 0 end) as obj2_count,
  sum(case when [object_name] = 'OBJ3' then 1 else 0 end) as obj3_count
from
  [objects]
```

An index on object_name would definitely be beneficial

Comment: Thanks for Reply..I need row values must come as column values in Dynmically

Comment: Dynamically? Perhaps you should specify that in the question- it is an important note to miss. You will have to look at using a `PIVOT`- even then though, you will have to have a fixed amount of columns. Without dynamic SQL, you won't be able to have a query that returns a variable amount of columns depending on values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a pivot:

```
SELECT * FROM [OBJECTS] 
PIVOT (COUNT([OBJECT_NAME]) 
FOR [OBJECT_NAME] IN ([OBJ1],[OBJ2],[OBJ3])) AS [OBJCount]
```

If you don't want to hard-code the column names you can get them using dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                            ',' + QUOTENAME(o.[OBJECT_NAME])
                   FROM     [OBJECTS] o
    FOR           XML PATH('')
                  ,   TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM [OBJECTS] 
                PIVOT (COUNT([OBJECT_NAME]) 
                FOR [OBJECT_NAME] IN (' + @cols + ')) AS [OBJCount]'


EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply..I need row values must come as  column values in Dynmically